# How can i build Angular project to hold all files, except of index.html in subdirectory

Tags: angular, webpack

I need to keep such structure of my 'dist' folder for ng builded project:

- dist

  - app-name
  - - -index.html
  - - build
  - - - \main.js
  - - - \ polyfills.js
  - - - \ and so on

Now i have all project files in one directory so its not good for me

How can i fix this?

Comment: What prevents you from moving all files to a subdirectory and amend paths?

Comment: I think its not best idea to do it with every new build...

Comment: it's more interesting **why** do you need this structure. Just because you don't like how it looks like? What is the problem you are trying to solve? This is a `dist` folder, it should not be human friendly

Comment: I'm amazed at amount of unhelpful comments to this post. I too, need the same thing. My reasons are valid, and I don't think OP needs to justify the "why". However if anyone out there knows how to do this with the cli adding a solution here would be nice. I'll do the same if I figure it out.